# What does this #define in Objective C do?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I've found that `#define`s can be used in Objective C to make a longer function smaller, but I'm not sure what it does here:

```
#define S(s) @#s
```

Later in the code the developer uses it in:

```
self.scopeDisplayNames = @[S(SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope), S(SPTAuthUserReadEmailScope)];
```

I'm very confused as to what it does. Also, is there a way to do this in Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: Well I assume you use it as a shortcut, but I'm not sure what this particular `#define` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Adrian is correct, but I think is missing the point, as are the comments.

Look at the code sample:

```
self.scopeDisplayNames = @[S(SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope), S(SPTAuthUserReadEmailScope)];
```

`SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope` is a global constant of type `NSString *` in the Spotify SDK. The macro call:

```
S(SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope)
```

expands to:

```
@"SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope"
```

which is the *variable name* as a string.

Why not write it directly as a string?

Because if you did you might make a simple spelling error which would not be caught by the compiler. By using the macro the argument is supported by Xcode's auto-complete – just start typing the name.

*So the macro is a way to avoid accidental spelling errors when needing to have the name of a variable as a string.*

Here is the auto-completion working in Xcode:

[image: auto-completion in Xcode]

The auto-completion box pops up automatically. If you start to type a string constant, e.g. `@"SPT`, then auto-complete will not automatically activate, however you can call it up by hitting the escape key.

HTH

Comment: The macro does not protect you against spelling errors at all. Auto-completion and compile-time checking are very different things. You can still make spelling errors with autocompletion and they won't be caught. It's still a literal string, only written in a more complicated way.

Comment: @Sulthan - once you type the opening " of a string constant then auto-complete of variable names does not function. However when you start typing a macro argument then auto-complete does work, and in the usage shown in the question you can complete the desired variable name without typing it all, after all that is the raison d'être of auto-completion surely? Whether this benefit justifies the use of the macro is another question, with a subjective answer!

Answer (score 3):

It declares a macro function that turns the parameter into a `NSString` literal. For example, `S(hi)` would expand to `@"hi"`.

For reference:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

And to answer your second question, there is no way to do this in Swift that I am aware of. It's not a good idea in either language, anyway.

Comment: So if I wanted to do this without the `#define` in Objective C, what would the `self.scopeDisplayNames = @[S(SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope), S(SPTAuthUserReadEmailScope)];` look like?

Comment: @user5812721 just replace `S(X)` with `@"X"`. It would be `@[@"SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope", @"SPTAuthUserReadEmailScope"];`

Comment: And indeed you should do this without macros – this is a horrible use of them. You're not even gaining any brevity, you're just needlessly sacrificing clarity and ease of debugging. If you need string constants, then define them as global C constants.